# How to make sure to get a value before an observable is executed?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a code where an observable is executed before the code that precedes it and the value it should use to query the data (`this.currentAccount.id`) is not there yet when it is executed.

How can I change it to make sure the ID is there?

I need to have the value of: this.currentAccount.id; before the query query['userId.equals'] = this.currentAccount.id; is executed.

`console.log('Print 1st: ', this.currentAccount.id);` is printed after `console.log('Print second', this.users);`

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.isSaving = false;
    this.principal.identity().then(account => {
        this.currentAccount = account;
        console.log('Print 1st: ', this.currentAccount.id);
    });
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ community }) => {
        this.community = community;
    });
    const query = {
        };
    if ( this.currentAccount.id != null) {
        query['userId.equals'] = this.currentAccount.id;
    }
    this.userService
        .query(query)
        .subscribe(
                (res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => {
                    this.users = res.body;
                },
                (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
    console.log('Print second', this.users);
```

Comment: move `console.log('Print second', this.users);` 3 lines up. inside the subscription.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I need to have the value of: this.currentAccount.id; before the query query['userId.equals'] = this.currentAccount.id; is executed.

Comment: you're mixing both promises and observables in the same code snippet ? why ? choose one and stick with it. on your issue, it seems you less eager to learn WHY it happens, and more eager to get a magic line that solves it all. ain't gonna happen.

Comment: No, I'm getting the currentAccount.id and then I'm querrying the userService to get the user. What do you mean? Please, show me your solution

Comment: the issue is you not getting javascript asnc behavior. you can't shoot out an async request (http request in your case it seems) and expect to have the result the next line. async requests take time. thats why you SUBSCRIBE, your code continues to execute, when the response arrives, it goes back to the `subscribe( (response) => {// this part} ))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a function call inside the subscription. The function will then be executed only when the subscription has finished.

```
this.userService.query(query)
  .subscribe((res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => {
    this.doSomething(res);
  }, (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message);

doSomething(res) {
  this.users = res.body;
  console.log(this.users);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log statement should reside in the subscription like that :

```
this.userService
    .query(query)
    .subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => {
                this.users = res.body;
                console.log('Print second', this.users);
            },
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    );
```

**Edit :** 
Move the following code (along with every dependent piece of code):

```
 if ( this.currentAccount.id != null) {
        query['userId.equals'] = this.currentAccount.id;
 }
```

to the subscription where you set the current account, so it becomes like that :

```
this.principal.identity().then(account => {
  this.currentAccount = account;
  console.log('Print 1st: ', this.currentAccount.id);

  const query = {
  };
  if (this.currentAccount.id != null) {
    query['userId.equals'] = this.currentAccount.id;
  }
  this.userService
    .query(query)
    .subscribe(
      (res: HttpResponse<IUser[]>) => {
        this.users = res.body;
      },
      (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
    );
});

this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ community }) => {
  this.community = community;
});
```

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is that I need to have the value of: this.currentAccount.id; before the query query['userId.equals'] = this.currentAccount.id; is executed.

Comment: Then just move the part of the query to the subscription, see my edit